# How can referenced parameters correctly be deduced using type traits

Tags: c++, function, templates, type-deduction, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to count the number of arguments in the passed method signature of a template. 
I want to know the number of arguments as this method is wrapped into a generic lamda and depending on the number of arguments passed, I will add a bit more information to the method passed in here.

I have isolated the issue to the snippit below. The snippit below works as expected but once I change the result method to take a reference of the METHOD, it fails compiling. Why s the reference on the paramter type influencing the type? How could I make it work with a reference?

Tested this with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

template <typename Func>
struct func_traits;

template <typename R, typename... TArgs>
struct func_traits<R(*)(TArgs...)> {
    static constexpr uint32_t ARG_COUNT = sizeof...(TArgs);
};

class TestClass {
public:
    // Compile error!!!
    // error C2027: use of undefined type 'func_traits<METHOD>'
    // uint32_t Result(const METHOD& function)

    template <typename METHOD>
    uint32_t Result(const METHOD function) {
        return (func_traits< METHOD >::ARG_COUNT);
    }
};


void foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
}

int bar()
{
    return 0;
}

int baz(double)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    TestClass device;

    std::cout << device.Result(foo) << std::endl;
    std::cout << device.Result(bar) << std::endl;
    std::cout << device.Result(baz) << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scenario in your example is very rare and is related to particular template rule related specifically to functions and array.

To elaborate if you have a template function which takes another function by reference then type deduced for T is actual function type (not pointer to function).
For e.g.

```
template<typename T>
void fun(const T& f);
{
.....
}
void print(int);
fun(print); //for this case T will be deduced as void(int) and not void(*)int i.e. T will not be a function pointer
```

So to get your example working for reference case you have to create one more template specialization like :

```
template <typename R, typename... TArgs>
struct func_traits<R(TArgs...)> {
    static constexpr uint32_t ARG_COUNT = sizeof...(TArgs);
};  //note (*) is removed from template function
```

**In short if you are passing function or array by value then they are decayed to pointer but if you are passing by reference then they are treated as it is.**
More details are available in Scott Meyers Effective Modern C++ (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch01.html)